# SQL GROUP BY while selecting the latest record + extra conditions

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to figure out what would be the most efficient way of achieving the following:

I have two tables:

```
word_translations(id, word_id, language_id)
```

and

```
translations(id, text, word_translation_id, created_at, updated_at, user_id)
```

So there is a one-to-many relationship between `word_translations` and `translations` table. If a translation is created with `user_id` not null, the user has provided his own translation and therefore overrides the default ones (there can be at most one (user) translation override per word_translation per user, but multiple default translations per word_translation).

I am trying to write SQL query, that returns a list of translation ids with following conditions:

- There is only a single translation id for each word_translation_id
- The translation id points to the latest translation of a specific word_translation (max(id)), unless there is other translation with the same word_translation_id that has user_id not null. In this case, it should point to translation id where the user_id is not null.

I have written the following query to do so, but I am not sure about it's performance:

```
SELECT IF(t2.id IS NULL, t1.id, t2.id) as id, t1.word_translation_id
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(t.id) as id, t.word_translation_id
    FROM translations t
    WHERE t.user_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.word_translation_id) as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.word_translation_id
    FROM translations t
    WHERE t.user_id IS NOT NULL) t2 
ON t1.word_translation_id = t2.word_translation_id;
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? (Also, do you see any issues with the query above?)

Comment: FYI `IF(t2.id IS NULL, t1.id, t2.id)` can be simplified to `IFNULL(t2.id, t1.id)`

Comment: If there are multiple user-provided translations for the word, this will return all of them. Is that what you want?

Comment: It's hard to tell the efficiency of queries, because the query planner will use different strategies depending on the table contents and how effective it expects the indexes to be. You generally need to benchmark different queries with the actual data.

Comment: Why doesn't this use `language_id` anywhere? You'll get the latest translation in any language.

Comment: And why mention the `word_translations` table at all if you don't use it in the query?

Comment: A better way to do it might be to write two queries: One returns the latest translation for words with no user-supplied translation, the other returns the user-supplied translations. Then combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: I dont think it can work with union as I need either the default translation id or the user provided translation id, which has priority

Comment: The query that returns default translation IDs excludes any words that have user-provided IDs, and vice versa. So there won't be any duplication in the two queries.

Comment: What about the result of the union? If there is both a default translation AND user translation, will not the union return both?

Comment: But there won't be. The query that returns default translations should exclude any words with user translations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first subquery (*derived table*) should be fast with an index on `(user_id, word_translation_id, id)`.

A `LEFT JOIN` to a *derived table* can be very slow, because there are no indexes to support the join.
And the table order cannot be swapped (in a `LEFT JOIN`) to use an index from the outer table.
But some derived tables can have an index. This is the case when the subquery has to be sorted anyway,
like in `GROUP BY` queries or queries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.
For example your first subquery will have an index on the `GROUP BY` columns.

Try to change your second subquery to

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t.id, t.word_translation_id
    FROM translations t
    WHERE t.user_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY t.word_translation_id, t.id
    LIMIT 99999999999999 ) t2 
ON t1.word_translation_id = t2.word_translation_id;
```

That should lead the derived table to have an index on `(word_translation_id, id )`,
which should be able to support the `ON` clause. But this will also lead to *filesort*
because we have a range condition in the WHERE clause.

A trick with an index on a virtual column can even get rid of the *filsort*.
What you need is an equality condition in the WHERE clause like `WHERE t.user_isset = 1`.

So let's create that virtual column and the index:

```
alter table translations
  add column user_isset tinyint as (user_id is not null),
  add index (user_isset, word_translation_id, id);
```

This is the perfect index for

```
WHERE t.user_isset = 1
ORDER BY t.word_translation_id, t.id
```

However - in your case the second subquery is not even necessary. You can also write the query this way:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.id, t1.id) as id, t1.word_translation_id
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(t.id) as id, t.word_translation_id
    FROM translations t
    WHERE t.user_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.word_translation_id) as t1
LEFT JOIN translations t2
  ON  t1.word_translation_id = t2.word_translation_id
  AND t2.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

But here you have the same problem with `t2.user_id IS NOT NULL`, which is a range condition.
So you would need another index here begining with `word_translation_id`, ideally on `(word_translation_id, user_id, id)`.
Or you could use the virtual column and index above, and change the condition `t2.user_id IS NOT NULL` to `t2.user_isset = 1`,
using a perfect, covering index.

Another simple solution is to use a correlated subquery with `LIMIT 1` to get the desired `translations.id` for each `word_translations.id`.

```
select w.id as word_translation_id,
(
  select t.id
  from translations t
  where t.word_translation_id = w.id
  order by t.user_id desc, t.id desc
  limit 1
) as id
from word_translations w
```

Best index for this query would be `(word_translation_id, user_id, id)`.
But this relies on NULLs being always sorted first. If you want to avoid it,
you can again use a virtual column with an index:

```
alter table translations
  add column user_isset tinyint as (user_id is not null),
  add index (word_translation_id, user_isset, id);
```

And the query:

```
select w.id as word_translation_id,
(
  select t.id
  from translations t
  where t.word_translation_id = w.id
  order by t.user_isset desc, t.id desc
  limit 1
) as id
from word_translations w
```

`order by t.user_isset desc, t.id desc` works here, because we either get the only row with `user_isset = 1`,
or if not present - the row with `user_isset = 0` and the highest `id`.

This query should be pretty fast and difficult to beat performance wise on many datasets.
It is *O(m * log(n))*, with *m* = rows in `word_translations` and *n* = rows in `translations`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So as far as I understand, its generally not a good idea to use  is (not) null in the where clause as it might affect performance? I am using MySQL, perhaps the database engine can have this optimized somehow? Also, is it generally a good idea to place a subquery in the select query? I assume the subquery will get executed separately for each row? Is that faster then doing a join directly?

Comment: `x IS NOT NULL` is a range condition like `x > 0`. There is nothing wrong with range conditions, and you cannot always avoid them. The problem is in the use of an index. If a column of an index has been used for a range condition, folowing columns in the index will be useless for search. E.g.: `where x = 1, y > 5, z = 7` if you have an index on `(x,y,z)`, then the engine can use the x-part for `x = 1` the y-part for `y > 5` but not the last part for `z = 7`. The range (all rows with  x = 1 and y > 5) have to be scanned to find `z = 7`. But an index on `(x, z, y)` would be fine.

Comment: Same for subqueries. They can be performant or not. There is no general X is faster than Y (like JOIN is faster than subquery).

Answer (score 2):

Use two queries that you combine with `UNION`.

Query 1 returns the newest default translation for words that don't have any user translations.

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id), t1.word_translation_id
FROM translations AS t1
LEFT JOIN translations AS t2 ON t1.word_translation_id = t2.word_translation_id AND t2.user_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.word_translation_id
```

Query 2 returns user translations.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, word_translation_id
FROM translations
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
```

Final query:

```
SELECT MAX(t1.id) AS id, t1.word_translation_id
FROM translations AS t1
LEFT JOIN translations AS t2 ON t1.word_translation_id = t2.word_translation_id AND t2.user_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.word_translation_id

UNION ALL

SELECT id, word_translation_id
FROM translations
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you say this query is more efficient than the one I described in my question? (Mainly asking because yours does an extra join)

Comment: Why `DISTINCT`? Isn't `id` the primary key?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I wasn't sure when I wrote the answer, but you're probably right.

Comment: @Adam It's really hard to predict efficiency with MySQL. But both versions just have one join: Mine self-joins the table, yours joins subqueries. The latter may not be able to take advantage of indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to simplify this using an anti-join:

```
SELECT MAX(t.id) AS id, t.word_translation_id
FROM translations t
LEFT JOIN translations t2 ON
    t.user_id IS NULL
    AND t.word_translation_id = t2.word_translation_id
    AND NOT (t.id = t2.id)
    AND (t2.id > t.id OR t2.user_id IS NOT NULL) 
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.word_translation_id
```

For each translation, look for another translation for the same word that has either a later id, or a user_id that is not null (the `JOIN` conditions).  Then exclude any rows where that is true (the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: This only returns one translation per ID, not all the translations with `user_id IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: That was my understanding of the first bulleted condition - unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Their conditions are not very clear. In the "unless" part, it doesn't say which of the other translations it should use. But your solution may be right.

Comment: I thought they implied that their query works, they're just concerned about the performance. And it returns all the user-defined translations, not just the latest.

Comment: Ah, I think I have the user constraint the wrong way round - let me fix that...

Comment: I was probably not clear enough in the description, but there can be at most one user provided translation, while many default translations.